# How can I start a login shell with options?

Tags: bash, login, passwd, restricted-shell

I am messing around and want to have a guest user whose login shell is a restricted one like `rbash`. Unfortunately there is no `rbash` executable anywhere on my Slackware installation, so I have to do `bash -r` instead.

I tried putting this in /etc/passwd as the login shell for the user in question:
`guest:x:1001:1001::/home/guest:/bin/bash -r` but it seems to be trying to find an executable with `" -r"` at the end of the filename and so doesn't let me log in because it doesn't exist.

Is there any way I can start a restricted shell with an option like this, or do I have to install an rbash binary? This is not ideal as I am on a Raspberry Pi (ARM) and may have to compile a package which is something I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: I don't think there is an "rbash binary" - it's just a symlink to `bash`, which uses `argv[0]` to decide whether to run in restricted mode. At least that's how it appears to work on Debian-based systems.

Comment: Can symlinks pass options to executables they point to? If so how do you do it?

Comment: Yeah, I can do whatever I like with it.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll write an answer explaining exactly what I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All I had to do was create a symlink at `/bin/rbash` pointing to `/bin/bash`, and `bash` must know that is was invoked from a link called `rbash` and starts itself in restricted mode.

Thanks for your help.